# Looking for possible Hercules legendary journeys episode

Tags: identify-this-tv-show, identify-this-episode

Yes, I mean this series:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hercules:_The_Legendary_Journeys

Anyway, I'm not entirely sure if this is indeed an episode of the series since I cannot find an episode that fits what I'm gonna describe, but anyway, here are the story points:

- The two protagonists are looking for some cure for an old king, I think, who is either in in a coma or too ill to stay conscious and is bedridden. Apparently, the Kings son is accompanying them
- The antagonist is a bearded villain with black colored hair.
- I remember in an earlier scene that the two protagonists are fighting each other whilst standing on poles, and a centaur is nearby observing them.
- During the near end, they find the cure/potion and pour it into the kings mouth. He awakens, but he then comically gets his neck broken by the bearded antagonist a few moments later.
- The two protagonists then fight the villain on top of several poles, and below the poles a huge fire ignites. The fight ends with the villain falling to the firey inferno below.

Now either this is an episode from the tv series or the longer lengthed made for tv movies of the franchise, I dunno.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, you seem to be looking for the spin off *Young Hercules*'s [pilot movie](http://hercules-xena.wikia.com/wiki/Young_Hercules_(film)) (essentially episode 0).

> Alcmene, fearing she will lose her son, sends Hercules to Cheiron's academy. Once there, he meets up with Iolaus, a pain in the neck who he knew from his own village; Jason, The Crowned Prince of Corinth; and the female cadet Yvenna. Shortly after their introduction, the friends set sail with some fellow cadets on a mission. They must search for the Golden Fleece in order to save Jason's father who is on his death bed. Unbeknown to the cadets, is that Ares and Discord are the ones who put him there.

When Jason cures his father with the golden fleece, black-haired, bearded villain Ares immediately breaks his neck. And earlier on, Hercules and Jason fight on pillars while a centaur observes them. The latter scene was recreated in the [show](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_Hercules) that followed, where the lead was played by Ryan Gosling. The movie is currently available [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=objH7P3JI8Y).

[image]